# Is it worthwhile changing a C declaration to add type safety?

Tags: c, type-conversion, header-files, void-pointers

I'm wondering is it reasonable, or worthwhile, overriding header declarations in order to set a particular type. In preference to something like void * which adds no type safety.

For example, if you have a generic storage function that adds a sensor reading to a circular buffer:

```
int add_reading(void *);
```

In order to be generic, the function has to be defined as a void *. However, in the header file, you could declare the function as:

```
int add_reading(my_reading_t *);
```

which would add a degree of type safety over the void pointer. In a generic header, you could set the type with a #define that defaulted to void. Thus the override type could be defined just before the #include.

It seems an unnecessary hack, but one could argue the same for opaque pointers too - using opaque_type_t * in preference to void *. But that at least is defined behaviour. What I wonder is if this type of messing invokes UB (undefined behaviour)?

Comment: If you are planning to have a `#define` right before you `#include` your header, then I think that's a really bad idea. Not the most scalable concepts. What if you want to use the function with different types in the same file?

Comment: Erm. You are correct - there is indeed a basic assumption in the code that the function will only be used with one type. Actually there's a comment "there will only be one of these so a local static structure keeps state" :-)

Comment: If you have a generic function, you should probably be passing the size of whatever you're manipulating as well as the pointer to the data.  Unless, perhaps, what you're storing is the pointer itself, without any interpretation of it.  I'd go for type-safe cover functions: `static inline int add_my_reading(my_reading_t *r) { return add_reading(r); }` is sufficient (assuming you're only storing pointers and don't need the size).  You may also need different circular buffers for each different type, in which case the interface needs more upgrade work, to include a 'ring buffer handle pointer'.

Comment: The comment by DeiDei is the correct answer. This is not a scalable concept. It was actually code that is used in one place and now being used in more than one place - which means it should be either written properly or copied/pasted and adapted individually. Not a half way house. I'm being lazy...

Comment: +1 Jonathan Leffler - I have an init function that does exactly that - passes the size of what I'm manipulating. But I like the static inline function; it's is a nice way of dealing with this problem with minimal messing. Thanks.

Comment: If you're careful, your header can define the cover functions, and have `#define add_reading(r) do not call add_reading directly` afterwards to prevent accidental  use of the raw function.  As it stands, someone could achieve deliberate use: `(add_reading)(r);` would call the raw function despite the function-like macro.  Using `#define add_reading do not use add_reading directly` prevents that misuse too. `#undef` can still be used — but there comes a point at which you're trying to protect against malice, not accident, and it is simply better to get coders who adhere to the manual and rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function declared with `int add_reading(void *)` is not compatible with a function defined with `int add_reading(my_reading_t *)`. The behavior of calling a function defined with the latter using an identifier declared with the former (or other function designator with that type) will not be defined by the C standard, per C 2018 6.5.2.2 9:

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.

Per 6.7.6.1 2:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

Obviously, the parameter types `void *` and `my_reading_t *` are not pointers to compatible types (presuming `my_reading_t` is a structure type, is not an alias for `void`).

Per 6.7.6.3 15:

> For two function types to be compatible,… corresponding parameters shall have compatible types…

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: No. The relevant passage of the C standard is quoted in my answer. Pointers to objects can be converted to and from `void *`, but that does not mean they are compatible types. C 6.2.5 says pointers to void and pointers to characters must have the same representation and alignment requirements, and a footnote says this is meant to imply they are interchangeable, apparently overriding the other compatibility rules. Similarly, pointers to structures must be the same as each other, but not as pointers to void. And pointers to unions form another class, distinct from structures.

Comment: Yes, the old Undefined Behaviour. In my heart I often say "look, it's an address, it'll be fine". Doesn't mean it's Right and Proper though. Conversions to void * are not the same as "let's pretend this is a void * and sure, it's fine". Until gcc optimises something and it all goes to pot. I sometimes feel the same about memset with zero and pointers (NULL is not necessarily all-bits 0) but hey, you know, whatever :-)

Comment: I believe where 6.7.6.1.2 differs from nit picking is with optimising compilers. I'm thinking gcc -O2 could make assumptions about incompatible types not pointing to the same address and optimise access based on that. Possibly leading to odd bugs.

Answer (score 3):

What you propose looks like a bad idea.  If you want to promote type-safety such that it cannot compile if you try to pass in the wrong type, you could try to make use of C11's `_Generic`.

```
int add_reading (void *);
#define ADD_READING_HELPER(X) _Generic((X), \
    my_reader_t *: add_reading((X)) \
)

int main(void) {
    my_reader_t good;
    printf("%d\n", ADD_READING_HELPER(&good)); // works because _Generic has a rule for dealing with (my_reader_t *)
    int bad;
    printf("%d\n", ADD_READING_HELPER(&bad)); // fails to compile because the _Generic does not have a rule for dealing with (int *)
}

int add_reading (void *arg) {
    // whatever the function does
}
```

Essentially `_Generic` allows you to perform different actions based on the controlling type of the expression passed into it, which is all determined at compile-time.  What we're doing here is creating a rule for `my_reader_t *`, but no other types, so attempting to pass anything other than `my_reader_t *` into the `_Generic` will prevent the program from compiling as it doesn't have any rules on what to do with that type.

Comment: That's a clever use of generic selection.  I had never thought of using it that way before.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Wish I could take credit for the idea, but I'd seen someone else do it before.

Comment: Neat idea. Furthermore, you could name the macro the same `#define add_reading(X) _Generic((X),  my_reader_t *: add_reading((X)) ` so that calls are typesafe but using `add_reading` where a `int (*)(void *)` is expected will still work.

Comment: @PSkocik That is interesting.  It didn't work for me initially because I had all of my test code in a single file, and by having the function definition come after the `#define ...`, it was replacing the actual function definition with the `_Generic` stuff, and it did not like that. `error: expected identifier or '('`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You can also preven the expension with parentheses. `int (add_reading)(void *X) { /*definition*/ }`  will not expand `add_reading` as a function-like macro.